Rails 7: How to debug blue screen error ("We're sorry, but something went wrong.") on production?
I am using Dokku to deploy the application on the production server. On some pages, my application crashes with this blue screen:

I logged in on the server and ran dokku log my-app-name with hope I'll see the error - but unfortunately, there was no error in the log.
Then I looked to /var/log/nginx/my-app-name-error.log - no error caught either, only the last known request before the error happened. Also, I looked to /var/log/nginx.error.log - and again, no error.
I also have integrated Rollbar, but it didn't catch any error either. Finally, I set config.consider_all_requests_local to true for production in the Rails app, but it didn't provide any error indication neither.
Any advice how do I find the problem causing the blue screen?

@dbugger no, not a single mention of an error in those places I looked at.

This is likely a class loading issue, somewhere early in the pipeline. In your development.rb, set config.eager_load = true and start up the app, and it should reproduce locally.

I don't know dokku, but the log you need to look at is the rails_root/log/production.log... is this what you're getting from dokku log my-app-name?

check puma logs

This could be related to the BetterErrors debugging live shell. By default it is only available to localhost, but if you run your application in a container, you'll need to allowlist your local network stack.
Put the following in your config/environments/development.rb
# Private subnets defined by RFC1918 as stated in https://docs.docker.com/v1.5/articles/networking/
BetterErrors::Middleware.allow_ip! '10.0.0.0/8'
BetterErrors::Middleware.allow_ip! '172.24.0.1/12'
BetterErrors::Middleware.allow_ip! '172.16.0.0/12'
BetterErrors::Middleware.allow_ip! '192.168.0.0/16'

